# OpenStack Dashboard Layout Customization

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

Hi I am following the official tutorial of openstack dashboard layout customization [here](https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/pike/admin/customize-configure.html). It says that I need to remove openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme. But wouldn't removing this theme before customization will break anything? Also after removing the theme what do I need do...do I need to install some other theme to replace it?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your first question, by removing the theme before customization will not break anything since it will use the default Horizon (OpenStack Dashboard) theme.

I am not sure how you deploy your OpenStack and what version of your dashboard. But in default Devstack, you will see the default theme of the Horizon.

To see what to do, please take a look at this link: https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/configuration/themes.html

This works for the horizon in any vender.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the solution above. But I've followed the link and its a bit complicated. I would really really appreciate if you can just give me one solid clue and I will get started. Like please tell me how can I add background to default white login page for any other color. This small help will let me understand the complete structure. Thanks again for the response above.

Comment: Something like this but this is a script and in my case its a simple image. https://testdrive.stratoscale.com/login

Comment: will get back to you with an example. But you could try to use the developer tool (either chrome or firefox) and change the CSS from there so you will see how to get started.

Comment: I would really appreciate and example also. One example will do for me. Thanks again :-)

Comment: okay, so for example, if you change `Log in` to `Sign in` here: https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/93904437f47481a523d1c09a95c507e6a706ad49/horizon/templates/auth/_login_form.html#L17 You will see in the default horizon login page, the context changes to `Sign in`